# High CPU Usages After Migrating Wordpress in Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: server, 20.04, php, cpu, nginx

I am using a WordPress site with Woocommerce in a managed hosting service. I have taken 8GB ram's new AWS t3.large ec2 instance and installed PHP and MariaDB 10.4. After migrating my website is running but I noticed that my CPU usage went up to 90%. And it's not decreasing.

Here is the CPU usage screenshot.
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFb9P.png)

Here is my nginx config

```
server {
    server_name beta.website.com www.beta.website.com;
    root /var/www/html/website;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    #client_max_body_size 100M;
    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
     }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ ^/wp-json/ {
        rewrite ^/wp-json/(.*?)$ /?rest_route=/$1 last;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico{
          log_not_found off;
          access_log off;
      }

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl/beta_website/beta.website.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl/beta_website/beta.website.key;

}
server {
    if ($host = beta.website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name beta.website.com www.beta.website.com;
    return 404; 


}
```

**Information**

My MySQL file size is 146MB and the backup file size is 7.5GB. My php.ini config's memory was set to 512MB.
When I saw the CPU usages I had disabled the server block in Nginx and then the server usage went to 45% and when I remove the project directory from `/var/www/html` the current CPU usages is less than 1%.

**Where am I making mistake?**

Comment: What's the problem with the CPU at 90%? Resources are to be used.

Comment: Sorry forget to mention, there are 2 other sites running, one is in PHP and another one is static react. And the other website including WordPress become super slow.

Comment: The MySQL instance using this much CPU is unusual. WordPress is not a heavy database client. I would turn on general logging in MySQL for a while, and see what is going on there.

Comment: When your MySQL load is high, it may be useful to log into the database and use the `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` command, which will list all of the currently-running SQL queries. If there are some queries that need tuning, this is one way you can find them.